# Read specific character from file using JavaScript AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to find a way of reading data extracts from data files, where some of these files are quite large. The specific character place in the file is known and can be extracted using JavaScript code similar to that below (using JQuery).

The problem I am having is that my code reads the entire file into the buffer before processing, and for large files this is impractical. Is there a way that either code below can be altered or would perhaps a more efficient method be possible?

```
function startfn() {


    var index = 1000;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "datafile.bin",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {procData(data,index);}
    })


    return 0;
}

function procData(strData, index) {

    alert(strData.charCodeAt(index).toString(16) 
    +","+strData.charCodeAt(index+1).toString(16) +", "+
    strData.charCodeAt(index+2).toString(16));

}
```

Comment: ajax (js) does not have direct read/write access to do that sort of thing.  You need to write a server-side script that opens and reads the file line by line (or seeks to the specific point) and return relevant data.  Then make the ajax request to the script.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way of seeking remotely into a file at a precise location using AJAX. You should do that on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use a **backend** service (Php for example) that do the extraction then just use ajax to get the result.